# Call recording in android

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, phone-call, voice-recording

**Update**: Seems like `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` is not supported anymore my android. but need some alternatives to do.

I tried to record call using MediaRecorder. But i can't able to hear the receiver voice saved file in Android 6.0. My code is below

```
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(setFileName());
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

I tried changing `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` to `VOICE_CALL`. But getting exception in `mediarecorder.start()`.

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: You cannot record receiver's voice call without putting the Speaker ON

Comment: @DanyPoplawec then how can we make the recording possible ?

Comment: AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) Sos.getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

Comment: @DanyPoplawec you want me to make MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL ?

Comment: @SteveSmith  im getting below exception when i changed audiosource to voice_call  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.ramola.callrecord.CallManager.ManagerCall: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.

Comment: ist it working on versions < 6.0? maybe you didn't check if all needed permissions are granted?

Comment: @katharine i made all permissions. Problem is recorder.Starr() failed